# java functional interface and lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

functional interface

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public interface EmployeeAudit {

    public ArrayList<String> fetchEmployeeDetails (double salary);
}
```

in public class Main

```
public static EmployeeAudit findEmployee(){
    ArrayList<String> name=new ArrayList<>();
    return  (sal) -> {
        employeeMap.forEach((key,value) -> {
            if(value<=sal) 
                name.add(key);
        });
        return name;
    };
}
```

In main function:

```
ArrayList<String> str = findEmployee().fetchEmployeeDetails(sal);
```

---

can anyone help me to understand how value of **sal** is transferred to findEmployee(), as findEmployee() is called first as per the chaining. And how these calls are working.

Comment: Would you be able to answer your own question if you replaced the lambda expression with an anonymous class implementing `EmployeeAudit`?

Comment: Always avoid mutating external references in lambda. A better version is:  `EmployeeAudit aud = sal -> employeeMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> sal >= e.getValue()).map(Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method `findEmployee()` does in fact **instanciate** an `EmployeeAudit` object. `EmployeeAudit` is an interface so it needs to define its method, as their is  only one, it is a functionnal interface and can be done with a lambda but thta is equivalent to

```
public static EmployeeAudit findEmployee() {
    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    return new EmployeeAudit() {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> fetchEmployeeDetails(double sal) {
            employeeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
                if (value <= sal)
                    name.add(key);
            });
            return name;
        }
    };
}
```

Then, on that instance, you call the `fetchEmployeeDetails` method, and that is maybe easier to see with splitting the code

```
EmployeeAudit ea = findEmployee();
ArrayList<String> str = ea.fetchEmployeeDetails(10);
```

---

You could even imagine create the class implementing `EmployeeAudit` and use very easily

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

interface EmployeeAudit {
    ArrayList<String> fetchEmployeeDetails(double salary);
}

public class Test {
    static Map<String, Integer> employeeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        employeeMap.put("Jean", 10);
        employeeMap.put("Jean2", 100);
        employeeMap.put("Jean3", 100);
        EmployeeAudit ea = new EmployeeAuditImpl();
        ArrayList<String> str = ea.fetchEmployeeDetails(10);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    static class EmployeeAuditImpl implements EmployeeAudit {
        @Override
        public ArrayList<String> fetchEmployeeDetails(double sal) {
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
            employeeMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
                if (value <= sal)
                    name.add(key);
            });
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so this overriding of the abstract method happens only in the case of functional interface? So, as much I understand your answer. because our findEmployee() has a return type of interface EmployeeAudit thus it will create an instance of it and thus its member function in this case fetchEmployeeDetails() can be accessed. Now can you explain me a bit more on how lambda function in return statement of findEmployee() overrides the fetchEmployeeDetails()?

Comment: @varun Read about "functional interface" like  https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces. Any method can defined with a lambda, BUT in case of an interface with a single method can also be defined with a lambda : that is a functional interface

Answer (score 1):

`findEmployee()` returns an anonymous function (actually a `EmployeeAudit` defined as a function because `EmployeeAudit` is a functional interface).

This function is defined as taking an input parameter called `sal` but this is not the `sal` of your main call: you could rename `sal` to anything else in `findEmployee` and the code would work the same.

The inner `sal` is the name of a parameter like you could use in any other regular function:

```java
void someFunction(double sal) { ??? }
```